# How to create space between bar chart and data table using matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have been searching for hours how to add space between a bar chart and a table using matplotlib.pyplot but I haven't found a solution on how to display the layout properly. Currently  the top of the table collides with the bar chart x axis header and the bottom of the table is out of the figure. I have tried making the figure bigger with `figsize`, I have tried using `bbox`, `subplots_adjust`, `plt.tight_layout()` but none works. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

```
def plot_bar(df, *args):
    df = pd.DataFrame([{'OPEN': 4, 'CLOSED': 139, 'DATE': '2019-01-01'}, {'OPEN': 0, 'CLOSED': 139, 'DATE': '2019-02-01'}, {'OPEN': 1, 'CLOSED': 124, 'DATE': '2019-03-01'}, {'OPEN': 4, 'CLOSED': 127, 'DATE': '2019-04-01'}, {'OPEN': 1, 'CLOSED': 84, 'DATE': '2019-05-01'}, {'OPEN': 6, 'CLOSED': 113, 'DATE': '2019-06-01'}, {'OPEN': 0, 'CLOSED': 123, 'DATE': '2019-07-01'}, {'OPEN': 2, 'CLOSED': 109, 'DATE': '2019-08-01'}, {'OPEN': 0, 'CLOSED': 107, 'DATE': '2019-09-01'}, {'OPEN': 7, 'CLOSED': 119, 'DATE': '2019-10-01'}, {'OPEN': 2, 'CLOSED': 82, 'DATE': '2019-11-01'}, {'OPEN': 4, 'CLOSED': 83, 'DATE': '2019-12-01'}, {'OPEN': 12, 'CLOSED': 112, 'DATE': '2020-01-01'}, {'OPEN': 10, 'CLOSED': 89, 'DATE': '2020-02-01'}, {'OPEN': 31, 'CLOSED': 64, 'DATE': '2020-03-01'}])
    df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"])
    df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].apply(lambda x: [x.month, x.year])
    df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].apply(lambda x: f'{calendar.month_abbr[x[0]]}-{x[1]}')

    ax = df.plot.bar(x=args[0]['x'], y=args[0]['y'], figsize=(15, 7))
    for i, v in enumerate(df['OPEN']):
        ax.text(i - .20, v + 1, str(v), color='blue', fontweight='bold')
    for i, v in enumerate(df['CLOSED']):
        ax.text(i - .20, v + 1, str(v), color='orange', fontweight='bold')

    plt.title('Open vs Closed Tickets')
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Tickets')

    table_columns = df['DATE'].values.tolist()
    open = df['OPEN'].values.tolist()
    closed = df['CLOSED'].values.tolist()
    table_data = [open, closed]
    table_rows = df.columns.values.tolist()[0:2]
    plt.table(cellText=table_data, rowLabels=table_rows, colLabels=table_columns, loc='bottom',
              bbox=[0, -0.250, 1, 0.2])

    plt.tight_layout()

    plt.show()

    return
```

Answering Diziet Asahi: I made those 2 changes but my table somehow is still cut in half man this is so frustrating.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on *how* did `subplots_adjust()` not work? This should be the answer to your problem (actually the answer I wrote before I noticed you said you already tried)

Comment: Adding a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes a toy dataset (refer to [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)) would help tremendously

Comment: @DizietAsahi tbh i don't understand how the layout works but I tried using plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.7) and I see the same figure. I added the actual dataset at the start of the function if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

One possible issue is that you have to use [`plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=xxx)`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html) **after** `tight_layout()` (otherwise tight_layout will undo what you did with subplots_adjust). This will change the size of the plot and make more room for the table below. Increase the `xxx` value to suit your need, the value is given in fraction of the figure, so `bottom=0.2` would locate the bottom of the plot at 20% of the figure height.

The other issue is that you are using `plt.table()` which was made to have the table "stick" to the axes. If you place the table below the axes, then it's basically supposed to replace the x-axis labels. But you have to chose between using `loc=` (automatic placement) or `bbox=` (manual placement). You cannot use both.

Here is the results of doing those two things:

```
import calendar
df = pd.DataFrame([{'OPEN': 4, 'CLOSED': 139, 'DATE': '2019-01-01'}, {'OPEN': 0, 'CLOSED': 139, 'DATE': '2019-02-01'}, {'OPEN': 1, 'CLOSED': 124, 'DATE': '2019-03-01'}, {'OPEN': 4, 'CLOSED': 127, 'DATE': '2019-04-01'}, {'OPEN': 1, 'CLOSED': 84, 'DATE': '2019-05-01'}, {'OPEN': 6, 'CLOSED': 113, 'DATE': '2019-06-01'}, {'OPEN': 0, 'CLOSED': 123, 'DATE': '2019-07-01'}, {'OPEN': 2, 'CLOSED': 109, 'DATE': '2019-08-01'}, {'OPEN': 0, 'CLOSED': 107, 'DATE': '2019-09-01'}, {'OPEN': 7, 'CLOSED': 119, 'DATE': '2019-10-01'}, {'OPEN': 2, 'CLOSED': 82, 'DATE': '2019-11-01'}, {'OPEN': 4, 'CLOSED': 83, 'DATE': '2019-12-01'}, {'OPEN': 12, 'CLOSED': 112, 'DATE': '2020-01-01'}, {'OPEN': 10, 'CLOSED': 89, 'DATE': '2020-02-01'}, {'OPEN': 31, 'CLOSED': 64, 'DATE': '2020-03-01'}])
df["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATE"])
df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].apply(lambda x: [x.month, x.year])
df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].apply(lambda x: f'{calendar.month_abbr[x[0]]}-{x[1]}')

ax = df.plot.bar(x='DATE', y=['OPEN','CLOSED'], figsize=(15, 7))
for i, v in enumerate(df['OPEN']):
    ax.text(i - .20, v + 1, str(v), color='blue', fontweight='bold')
for i, v in enumerate(df['CLOSED']):
    ax.text(i - .20, v + 1, str(v), color='orange', fontweight='bold')

plt.title('Open vs Closed Tickets')
plt.ylabel('Tickets')

#remove all x-labels since the table will be used instead
plt.xlabel('')
plt.xticks([])


table_columns = df['DATE'].values.tolist()
open = df['OPEN'].values.tolist()
closed = df['CLOSED'].values.tolist()
table_data = [open, closed]
table_rows = df.columns.values.tolist()[0:2]
plt.table(cellText=table_data, rowLabels=table_rows, colLabels=table_columns, loc='bottom')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried making those changes but it didn't work. Something I notice is that i can remove ```plt.tight_layout()``` and ```plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1)``` completely and the graph stays the same.